# Go back to the previous page twice on click

Tags: jquery

I'm having this script

```
$('#verder').click(function(){
    if(document.referrer.indexOf(window.location.hostname) != -1){
        parent.history.back();
        return false;
    }
});
```

so on click of #verder it will go back like you clicked ones on the back button of your browser.

so now my problem i need to make it go back 2 times.

how can i fix this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`History.go`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.history#go) can do that:

```
parent.history.go(-2);
```

Comment: @IvoJonkers: I'm not sure, that's just what it's called. "Go back 2 in history", I suppose?

Comment: strange when you go back just ones your not using .go

Comment: @IvoJonkers: Yep, it says that it's just shorthand for `.go(-1)`.

Comment: oke thank you and good luck on your quest to become a stackoverflow moderator